# define $ f:[0,1] \rightarrow [0,1]$ by $f(x ) = (2^k-1)/2^k ~for ~ x\in [ (2^{k-1}-1)/2^{k-1},~ (2^k-1)/2^k], k \geq 1$

Tags: real-analysis

define $ f:[0,1] \rightarrow [0,1]$ by $f(x ) = (2^k-1)/2^k ~for ~ x\in [ (2^{k-1}-1)/2^{k-1},~ (2^k-1)/2^k], k \geq 1$

Then prove that:
$1/20<\int_{0}^{1} f(x) dx<211/213$

Attempt: I was able to prove $\int_{0}^{1} f(x) dx$ lies between $(1/2,1)$ by taking the smallest value and largest value of f but got no idea as to how to bring those kind of figures in the range.

f is piecewise constant. That makes computing the integral just summing the values of f multiplied by length of the corresponding interval. But, what is special about the numbers on both sides of the inequality then?

Thanks

Comment: $f$ is piecewise constant. That makes computing the integral just summing the values of $f$ multiplied by length of the corresponding interval.

Comment: yeah, I too followed the same procedure. But, what is special about the numbers on both sides of the inequality then?

Comment: Nothing at all, it's just for confusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The integral evaluates to a sum

$$\int_0^1 f(x) dx=\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{2^k}\left(1-\frac{1}{2^k}\right) = \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{2^k} - \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{4^k} = \frac{2}{3}$$

Clearly, $1/20<2/3<211/213$.

Comment: Two-thirds, actually.

Comment: Yes, thank you. Edited.